# SOLVED Set MaterialTextInputEditText as full screen

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

at the screenshot you can see my actually situation. I would like to display the "Note" text field as a "full screen". How can i realize this?
How can I change the field `android:id="@+id/body_edit"` so that it fills the screen completely? Is there any option or is there a trick to do this? Do I have to change the line height in the linearLayout?

[image: screenshot of Leafpad]

My `activity_note_edit.xml` is here

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/all"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    tools:context="com.git.amarradi.leafpad.NoteEditActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/ScrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="false"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                    android:id="@+id/default_text_input_layout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                        android:id="@+id/title_edit"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="top"
                        android:hint="@string/title_hint"
                        android:inputType="text"
                        android:maxLines="@integer/maxLines" />
                </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">
                    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                        android:id="@+id/body_edit"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:ems="5"

                        android:gravity="top"
                        android:hint="@string/body_hint"

                        android:inputType="textMultiLine|textCapSentences" />
                </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Set `android:fillViewport="false"` to `true` and `TextInputEditText` to `match_parent`